# Is it possible to open 2 streams from the same microphone on Oboe?

Tags: android, c++, audio, audio-processing

I'm trying to open 2 input streams from the same microphone on Oboe but it's not working.

One of the audio inputs I'm opening is like this:

```
defaultBuilder().setDirection(oboe::Direction::Input)
        ->setFormat(oboe::AudioFormat::Float) // For now
        ->setChannelCount(1) // Mono in for effects processing
        ->openManagedStream(inStream);
```

then in the other:

```
builder.setChannelCount(channelCount)
            ->setDirection(isInput ? oboe::Direction::Input : oboe::Direction::Output)
            ->setSharingMode((oboe::SharingMode) oboe::SharingMode::Shared)
            ->setPerformanceMode((oboe::PerformanceMode) performanceMode)
            ->setInputPreset((oboe::InputPreset)inputPreset)
            ->setSessionId((oboe::SessionId) sessionId)
            ->setSampleRate(sampleRate)
            ->setFormat((oboe::AudioFormat) format)
            ->setChannelConversionAllowed(channelConversionAllowed)
            ->setFormatConversionAllowed(formatConversionAllowed)
            ->setSampleRateConversionQuality((oboe::SampleRateConversionQuality) rateConversionQuality)
            ;
```

Is it possible that because of the different properties of each open, things dont work? One of them is mono for processing some effects and the other is stereo for voice recording. The format may differ too, I don't know.

But in principle, I think it should be possible. Android should just split the microphone input into 2 and then act accordingly for each stream.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not an android developer, so excuse me for my french =) but from what I saw android uses ALSA/OSS as default kernel driver for audio, ALSA doesn't support opening more then one pcm on the same device also the device doesn't support more then one stream.

you can read more about ALSA here: https://www.linuxjournal.com/article/6735
and about android audio here: https://source.android.com/devices/audio

So for your question the answer is NO, you cant open more than one stream, it just not supported by the driver and the device.

but basically you can implement some kind of buffer with one writer thread and 2 readers.

Answer (score 1):

It's not possible to open more than one microphone streams in android. It's an Android restriction and there is no straight solution for it except you want to make a custom android ROM and bypass this limitation. Please check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63496858/12175239) similar question that I answered.

Comment: but I wanted to open the same microphone stream twice. What is the shared mode used for then?

Comment: Some manufactures customize android based on their needs. Maybe shared mode works on some devices but typically it doesn't work in most devices especially those which use the standard version of Android. @GuerlandoOCs